# Backporting Java 1.5+ to 1.4

Tags: java, parameterized, backport

How to rewrite the following 1.5+ constructs to 1.4?

```
final class FooList<T> extends AbstractList<T> implements ...
{
    private T[] tab;
    ...
}

public ListIterator<T> listIterator() {...}

public int bar(int x, Collection<? extends T> c) {...}

for (Foo f : s.baz(x)) {...}

for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> e : p.entrySet()) {...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final class FooList extends AbstractList implements ...
{
    private Object[] tab;
    ...
}

public ListIterator listIterator() {...}

public int bar(int x, Collection c) {...}

for (Iterator it = s.baz(x).iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
  final Foo f = (Foo) it.next();
  ...
}

for (Iterator it = p.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
  final Map.Entry e = (Map.Entry) it.next();
  ...
}
```

Plus all the necessary downcasts, of course.

Answer (score 1):

There are few thing not supported in Java 1.4 in your code

1. Remove  form your code.
2. Use Object instead of your T reference.
3. Change for loop to old index based.

Comment: `final class FooList extends AbstractList ... { private Object[] tab;} `?

Comment: 3. -- indexing is not equivalent to for-each. One must use the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Retroweaver](http://retroweaver.sourceforge.net/), it allows to use some features of Java 5 in Java 1.4.